# How to derive this equivalence in propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

This is a homework assignment from a discrete math class that I never took - it asks how to prove the statement $\neg \neg p \equiv p$.

The catch is that only the following equivalences can be used:

- $(p \land T) \equiv p$
- $(p \lor F) \equiv p$
- $(p \lor T) \equiv T$
- $(p \land F) \equiv F$
- $(p \lor p) \equiv p$
- $(p \land p) \equiv p$
- $(p \lor q) \equiv (q \lor p)$
- $(p \land q) \equiv (q \land p)$
- $(p \lor q) \lor r \equiv p \lor (q \lor r)$
- $(p \land q) \land r \equiv p \land (q \land r)$
- $(p \lor (q \land r)) \equiv (p \lor q) \land (p \lor r)$
- $(p \land (q \lor r)) \equiv (p \land q) \lor (p \land r)$
- $p \lor (p \land q) \equiv p$
- $p \land (p \lor q) \equiv p$
- $p \lor \lnot p \equiv T$
- $p \land \lnot p \equiv F$

No De Morgan's laws or anything else. Any ideas?

Comment: To be right, this question is about *propositional* and not *first-order* logic.

Answer (score 2):

We have :

> $\lnot \lnot p \equiv \lnot \lnot p \land T$

$\equiv \lnot \lnot p \land (p \lor \lnot p)$

$\equiv (\lnot \lnot p \land p) \lor ( \lnot \lnot p \land \lnot p)$

$\equiv (\lnot \lnot p \land p) \lor F$

$\equiv (\lnot \lnot p \land p) \lor (p \land \lnot p)$

$\equiv [\lnot \lnot p \lor (p \land \lnot p)] \lor [p \lor (p \land \lnot p)]$

$\equiv (\lnot \lnot p \lor p) \land (\lnot \lnot p \lor \lnot p) \land (p \lor p) \land (p \lor \lnot p)$

$\equiv (\lnot \lnot p \lor p) \land T \land (p \lor p) \land T$

$\equiv (\lnot \lnot p \lor p) \land p$

$\equiv (p \lor \lnot \lnot p) \land p$

> $\equiv p \land (p \lor \lnot \lnot p) \equiv p$

and it's done.